# What does support email stand for in firebase general settings?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

[image]

What does support email do in image? I couldn't find any documents and i cant change it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not a programming problem.

Comment: @JJJ Im sorry im new so where can i ask my non-programming problems?

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for (*your favorite company*).](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mouse hover on the (?) icon you will read that "**This will be the email address presented to users when they are authenticating with Google**. It can be changed to your signed-in email or an email of a Google Group managed by you."

When a user is authenticating with the Google sign-in method he/she is presented a form in order to enter his/her credentials. On this form the support e-mail will appear, as the contact e-mail for the system with which the user is going to share his Google account infos (i.e. you app).

Comment: I have already red that.My english is not so good thats why i asked.    "This will be the email address presented to users when they are authenticating with Google"    What does this mean.when some one try to login with google they use my email if not why i have to set support email.

Comment: When a user is authenticating with the Google sign-in method he/she is presented a form in order to enter his/her credentials. On this form the support e-mail will appear, as the contact e-mail for the system with which you are  going to share your Google account infos (i.e. you app).